# How to grab item from jquery autocomplete select rather than just property

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

Using the following jquery autocomplete

http://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

I am trying to figure out how on select I can grab the object passed with all the properties rather than just a property.

My object looks like

```
{id: 123,
address:aaaa,
unique:true}
```

I alright slightly changed into pass in array of suggestion objects rather than just string

```
renderItem: function (item, search){
    return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item.id + '">' + item.address + '</div>';
},
```

But on select its just grabbing the data-val attribute

```
    that.sc.on('mousedown.autocomplete', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
        var v = $(this).data('val');
        that.val(v);
        o.onSelect(v);
        setTimeout(function(){ that.focus(); }, 10);
    });
```

What do I need to change in the markup or jquery that onselect it has the entire item to return ?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: This git may be easier for you to use: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about

```
var v = $(this).data('val');
```

This is returning the value of 'this'. If you simply want the object and all of its properties, just use $(this). Then if you need to get the value from 'v', you would do v.val().

Comment: I mean the object I pass to the renderitem has multiple properties, not all on display but still contained in the item. i.e. item.id, item.address, item.unique. When I pick an item I want the entire item available to me. Not just data-val which right now is just set to item.id

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please? I need to see where you are calling your functions, how "that" and "o" are being defined